# Does the Kinetic Jaunt spell allow the caster to end their turn in another creature's space?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

The spell [*kinetic jaunt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/kinetic-jaunt) from *Strixhaven: A Curriculum of Chaos* provides several benefits, including the following one (emphasis mine):

> You can move through the space of another creature, and it doesn’t count as difficult terrain. **If you end your turn in another creature’s space**, you are shunted to the last unoccupied space you occupied, and you take 1d8 force damage.

This leads me to my question:

**Does the *kinetic jaunt* spell allow me to end my turn inside a creature's space, which usually is forbidden by the rules?**

The rules on [moving around other creatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures) state:

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your move in its space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Kinetic Jaunt doesn't enable you to willingly end your turn in the creatures space.

You can move into a creature's space, but nothing in the text enables you to willingly end your turn in the creature's space, but when you unwillingly end your movement in that space, you are shunted out and take damage.

> You can move through the space of another creature, [...] If you end your turn in another creature’s space, you are shunted to the last unoccupied space you occupied, and you take [...] damage.

It doesn't explicitly state that you can do so, so it doesn't override the general rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can *try* to end your turn in another creature's space, but you will be shunted out and take damage.

The feature specifically says that you can't end your turn in another creature's space.

It isn't clear to me how exactly you could end up in another creature's space (you can't choose to), but I could see a DM ruling that something that made you move, like *Dissonant Whispers*, could drive you into another creature's space (you don't mind because you're so Kinetically Jaunty).

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. "If you end your turn" doesn't mean you are allowed to do so on purpose. It covers cases where the caster's speed is reduced during the move, or other cases where the casters stops there unwillingly.

Comment: @StarHawk that is also my concern, is it either a) an extra effect if you happen to end your turn in another creatures space or b) does it explicitly allow you to end your turn in a creatures space.

Comment: @TobiasF.: Unless it explicitly states you can willingly end your turn in another creature's space, it doesn't override the general rule that prevents you from doing so. It does override other specific parts of the rule – you can move through other creature's spaces (presumably, regardless of whether it's hostile to you; I can't confirm this without being logged into DDB on this computer), and other creature's spaces don't count as difficult terrain when you move through them – but it doesn't override the part about willingly ending your turn in another creature's space unless it says it does.

Answer (score -1):

### No

There is no specific rule in the spell that overrides the general prohibition on willingly ending your move in another creature’s space. There are, of course, lots of things that could cause this to happen *unwillingly*.